# How enable/disable @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity for @Service methods for testing scenario

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working with `Spring Framework` and `Spring Security`

About **Testing**

For a set of Test classes for `@Controller` **with** *security*, `.apply(springSecurity()` and `@WithUserDetails(value="something")` are used

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                             .apply(springSecurity())// <---
                             .build();
}
```

For *other* set of Test classes for `@Controller` **without** *security*, therefore `.apply(springSecurity())` *and* `@WithUserDetails(value="something")` are **not** used.

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)                              
                             .build();
}
```

Until here all about for `@Controller` *with* and *without* security work fine.

The problem is for the `@Service`, when `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` is defined and the `@Service` methods are annotated with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`, all the *other* Test classes for `@Service` where *security* is **not** required fail now with:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: 
    An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

Of course it because the `@Test` methods do not use `@WithUserDetails(value="something")`

Thus, practically `.apply(springSecurity())` does the job, but it for a **Web** environment through `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)`

But for the server side, where *security* is **not** needed, I have:

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class})
@ActiveProfiles(resolver=TestActiveProfilesResolver.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={LoggingTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode=MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class PersonaServiceImplTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonaServiceImplTest.class.getSimpleName());

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    ...
```

Thus `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)` has no sense to be used. What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: I would greatly advise against disabling security for testing. Security is a functional aspect of an application, and should be tested as well. The headaches you think you might save by disabling it now will be returned tenfold when you do find a regression where security is not behaving as expected. Similarly, splitting up tests as "security vs non-security" only leads to code duplication and maintainability issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@WithUserDetails` and `@WithMockUser` to test method security as well.
For the tests to pick up on method security, you need to include the class annotated with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` in the component classes used for loading the `ApplicationContext`.

For example, if the configuration class `SecurityConfig` is annotated with `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig { }
```

And the Service `MessageService` has a method using `@PreAuthorize`.

```java
@Service
public class MessageService {
    public String getHelloMessage() {
        return "Hello!";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String getGoodbyeMessage() {
        return "Goodbye!";
    }
}
```

Then you need to include both of those classes in the `MessageServiceTest` and you can use the security testing annotations.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SecurityConfig.class, MessageService.class})
public class MessageServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    MessageService messageService;

    @Test
    public void helloMessageReturnsHello() {
        assertThat(messageService.getHelloMessage()).isEqualTo("Hello!");
    }

    @Test(expected = AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException.class)
    public void goodbyeMessageWithoutUserThrowsException() {
        messageService.getGoodbyeMessage();
    }

    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    @Test
    public void goodbyeMessageWithAdminReturnsGoodbye() {
        assertThat(messageService.getGoodbyeMessage()).isEqualTo("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```